# JsonPath expression to filter using regex

Tags: regex, json, jsonpath

We are using a tool which uses jayway library for evaluating JSONpath expression. **Javascript does NOT seem to work with it**. How can I use regular expression in the JSONPath in such a case. For instance, in the below example I would like to filter all book titles whose title has the word "Sword" in it:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Comment: I would find a workaround instead of trying to use regular expression.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Jayway implementation](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) uses the Ruby regex operator:

```
$.store.book[?(@.title =~ /^.*Sword.*$/)]
```

To ignore case:

```
$.store.book[?(@.title =~ /^.*sword.*$/i)]
```

Comment: I tried the above expression with json-path-0.9.0 in the classpath (as the tool uses the version 0.9 internally) and the statement 
Object result = JsonPath.read(jsonStr, query); 
where jsonStr is the one shared in the example above. The result is an empty set

Comment: Regex support was added in 1.2.0.

Comment: Nice. If I want to get values of all keys that startswith title, How would I go about writing it?

Answer (score 2):

For the record, a workaround for conditional regex in Goessner's javascript JSONpath would be to write the query as follow:

```
$.store.book[?(/^.*sword.*$/i.test(@.title))]
```

Please see here
https://github.com/jpaquit/jsonpath/tree/0.8.5-+-regexp for "=~" syntax in JS lib.

Comment: Any clues as to what `i.test` is? :D

Comment: @bviktor "i" is the regex flag for "case-insensitive" and "test" is the dedicated JS function ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

You could use capturing group or lookbehind assertion.

```
"title":\s*"([^"]*\bSword\b[^"]*)"
```

Add case-insensitive modifier `i` if necessary. Grab the title string from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bN6aE7/1)