# JToken.SelectToken with regex for finding values that match a pattern?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

How can I use [JToken.SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) for finding values inside a path that match a pattern (e.g. find all values that are valid email addresses)? Is there any Regex compatibility like [other frameworks support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954720/jsonpath-expression-to-filter-using-regex)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere (I didn't find at least), but actually in last versions (starting with 11.0.1 it seems) it does. Syntax is `=~ /regex here/`. For example:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse("{\"Objects\": [{\"Email\": \"test@gmail.com\"}, {\"Email\":\"not an email\"}]}");
// returns only "test@gmail.com" token
var result = o.SelectToken(@"$.Objects[?(@.Email =~ /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/)]");
```

Comment: I actually tried that before and recieved an `exception:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: 'Could not read query operator.'`. Which json.net version are you using?

Comment: @AmirPopovich I'm using last nuget version, which is 11.0.1

Comment: Upgraded from 10.3 to 11 and this did work. Probably a new feature. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Regarding documentation, support for regular expressions is mentioned in the [11.0.1 release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1): *New feature - Added support for regex operator in JSON Paths*.  And it's described in a [blog post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2018/02/22/json-net-11-0-release-1-net-standard-2-0-jsonconverters-json-path-and-more) by James Newton-King: *Json.NET 11 adds support for the regular expression operator in JSON Path queries... *.  The blog post shows use of the `=~` operator for regex matching.