# mongodb / jsonpath / jmespath expression to filter object with properties that contain special or accented characters

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, jsonpath, jmespath

I need to filter the objects that contain special characters in this json. (I can either write a javascript or import and query the data in mongo. )

```
{
    "Detail": [{
            "name": "somename1",
            "text": "Sometext1"
        },
        {
            "name": "somename2",
            "text": "Sometext!"
        }, {
            "name": "somename3",
            "text": "método"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output

```
{
    "Detail": [
        {
            "name": "somename2",
            "text": "Sometext!"
        },
        {
            "name": "somename3",
            "text": "método"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to use regular expression in jsonpath or jmspath to do this?

I tried various approached to get closer to what I need such as these, but I'm blocked at this point

```
Detail[].text.contains(`é`) in jmespath

$.[?(@.text=~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$].text in jsonpath

db.test.find({'Detail.text': /[a-zA-Z0-9]*$]/}) in mongodb where 'test' is the collection
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/2282634

Comment: Thank you @Joe, this helps building the character class but I still can't figure out the syntax of using regex in to filter only the objects that have the properties with special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try this tool Jayway JsonPath https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

I tried it online here https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

In this picture you can see the output.

[image]

This is the regular expression I used

```
.Detail[?(@.text =~ /(?:^\W+\w*$)|(?:^\w+\W+$)|(?:^\w+\W+\w+$)/)]
```

I have divided the problem within three groups

1. The string starts with at least one special characters or not word characters ^\W+ and it is followed by zero or more word characters i.e. $éxito
2. The string starts with at least one word character ^\w+ and it is followed by zero or more not word characters \w* i.e. culminó, knowledge.
3. The string starts with at least one word character ^\w+ then it is followed by one or more not word characters \W+ and then at least one word character i.e. beneplácito, now|knowledge, what$$$$happen.

Each previous case is grouped using a non-capturing group (?:) and the logical operation used is OR (|) because your string could match any of the three groups.

I also used this tool https://regexr.com/ to prepare the regular expression

By the way, this is based on this answer [JsonPath expression to filter using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954720/jsonpath-expression-to-filter-using-regex)

Comment: Thank you so much.I couldn't figure out the syntax but this helped.