# JAVA: How to find all matches of a substring in a nested JSONString and replace with some text

Tags: java, json, regex

JSON String looks like

```
{
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500,
        "stamp" : "randomtestcasenumberwithtimeID2",
        "case" : 1
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "stamp" : "randomtestcasenumberwithtimeID3"
    
    },
}
}
```

I want to replace all instances of `"stamp"` with something static such `"stamp" : "Testing"`. How would I go about this? please note the value of "stamp" is random.

So after the search and replace both instance of `stamp` should have same value `"Testing"` Example

```
    {
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500,
        "stamp" : "Testing",
        "case" : 1
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "stamp" : "Testing"
    
    },
}
}
```

Comment: You can use a regex in JSONPath. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954720/jsonpath-expression-to-filter-using-regex

Comment: Unfortunately the path is not fixed. Sometimes it can appear in nested elements of jsons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```java
String json = "<your-json-here>";
String newValue = "Testing";
String newJson = s.replaceAll("\"stamp\"\\s*:\\s*\"(.*)\"", String.format("\"stamp\" : \"%s\"", newValue));
```

or even something like this:

```java
String s2 = s.replaceAll("(?<=\"stamp\")\\s*:\\s*\"(.*)(?=\")", ":\""+ newValue);
```